# Rails - Creating a GettingStarted Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Im working to create a getting started controller, that guides a new users through uploading a photo, finding friends, inviting people etc.

GettingStarted has no model itself, it just guides users through a wizard. A user could fully bypass this gettingstarted process without breaking the site. It's just a guide...

What I've done so far is:

1. Create a Route, Controller and Model:

**Route:**

```
  resources :getting_started  
  namespace :getting_started do
    resource :users, :only => [:edit, :update]
  end
```

**Controller:**

```
class GettingStartedController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @current_step = current_step
  end

protected

  def current_step
    current_step || steps.first
    return 1
  end

  def steps
    %w[step1 step2 step3]
  end

end
```

**Model**

```
class GettingStarted < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_writer :current_step
  attr_accessor :current_step

  def current_step
    #current_step || steps.first
    return 1
  end

  def steps
    %w[step1 step2 step3]
  end

  def next_step
    self.current_step = steps[steps.index(current_step)+1]
  end

  def previous_step
    self.current_step = steps[steps.index(current_step)-1]
  end

  def first_step?
    current_step == steps.first
  end

  def last_step?
    current_step == steps.last
  end

end
```

**View:**

```
<%= @current_step.inspect %>
        <% form_for @gettingstarted do |f| %>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%= link_to image_tag current_user.profile_pic.url(:large), :class => 'getting-started-profile-pic' %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="" class="getting-started-link">Upload a photo</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <table>
        <tbody>
        <% end %>
```

Right now I'm stuck on the issue that I need GettingStarted to guide users through existing models, not be a model itself. And I'm getting **undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class**

Suggestions, thoughts on the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your `GettingStarted` model doesn't have to inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` but it does, you are getting error because Base is expecting a table in your db called GettingStarteds, or something. If you want to keep the content dynamic, meaning saving it in the db so you can change it, then you are pretty close, you could use a natural language model like 'steps' and the steps have an order associated with them, then you can look up the step based on its order in the getting started controller. you can also use a vanilla workflow with a steps controller, and then rename the route in the routes with the `:as =>` option

if the steps are static you might want to explore some of the static page model libraries available like high voltage https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage